# Merge conflicts with project.pbxproj on Git - Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

Although I already read similar comments here, in this forum, I haven't found an approach that may be suitable for teamwork in a seamless way.

If you know what I mean, you already may found tricky working with git and the `project.pbxproj` file in Xcode, even when you are working in a different file.

Say,

- A developer: created Foo folder, adding foo.swift to the project.
- B developer: created Bar folder, adding bar.swift to the project.

Different paths... but you know, conflict! And as you may also noticed, leaving `project.pbxproj` out is not an option.

So my question is: How do you handle this in a professional manner, Git flow ready and easiest way.

Thank you all very much.

PS: I'm using currently Bitbucket and SourceTree if matters.

PS2: I'd like to avoid command line and manually file editing if possible.

Comment: Why is `project.pbxproj` special?  Conflicts can happen in any file.

Comment: The problem with the pbxproj file is that while it is a text file, its structure is a mess and resolving merge conflicts in there can be very painful.  For example, a problematic merge could raise 1k conflicts in a file hard to understand (uuids everywhere as references, etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a `.gitattributes` file and adding the following line:

`*.pbxproj merge=union`

Merges will happen automatically and without you having to touch anything.

Alternatively, you might try [mergepbx](https://github.com/simonwagner/mergepbx), which does a more intelligent merge.

Comment: Have tried... this is not bullet proof. I had a case, that the xcode project was not opening any more. needed to merge by hand.

Comment: @Primoz990 This will happen because sometimes merge both(union) will end up missing some commas etc. Then you need to fix it manually. So doing it by hand is sometimes better.

Answer (score 3):

1. New files are created by only one developer on "main-develop" branch.
2. Push new files to "main-develop"
3. Those files are implemented by other developers after pull

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the maintainers of [Kintsugi](https://github.com/Lightricks/Kintsugi/), a tool that intelligently merges the conflicts and promises to automatically solve 99.9% of the conflicts that occur in `project.pbxproj` files.

The readme also contains instructions on how to set it up as Git merge driver, so it will be applied automatically whenever a conflict in a `*.pbxproj` file occurs. I don't know of a way to do that from Sourcetree, but for most conflicts after setup you won't have to touch the command line again.